# What exactly is the distance of two elements in $C[0,1]$?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

If $C[0,1]$ — the set of all continuous functions from $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ — is equipped with the metric $||\cdot||_1$ (1-Norm), then what is the distance between some elements/functions f and g?

Hopefully the above makes sense, I need to know this in order to be able to solve the actual task. In a Dr. Math article I stumbled over the entity
$$||f-g||_p = \left(\int_a^b |f-g|^p~dx \right)^{1/p}$$

Would that be the answer (so in my case $\int_a^b |f-g|~dx$)?

Until now I have only worked with distances between (finite) vectors.

Comment: Yes you would be correct in letting $p=1$.

Comment: There's two steps: $d(f,g)=\|f-g\|$ is how the distance is defined in a normed space. And the formula you found (with $p=1$) is how to compute $\|f-g\|_1$ by the very definition of $\|\cdot\|_1$.

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct; in this case, the distance between two such functions is precisely the area of the region between their graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, whenever you have a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on some space, it automatically gives you a metric $d(f,g) = \|f-g\|$. (One says that the norm induces the metric.)  So,

- the norm $\|f\|=\int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx$ induces the metric  $d(f,g)=\int_0^1 |f(x)-g(x)|\,dx$
- the norm $\|f\|=\sup_{0\le x\le1} |f(x)| $ induces the metric  $d(f,g)=\sup_{0\le x\le 1}|f(x)-g(x)|$, and so on.